# PHP Как обратиться к элементу массива?

Tags: php, youtube

вывожу переменную `$dl` через `print_r`

```
print_r ($dl);
```

Результат

> YoutubeDl\YoutubeDl Object ( [options:protected] => Array ( [extract-audio] => 1 [audio-format] => mp3 [audio-quality] => 0 [output] => %(title)s.%(ext)s ) [binPath:protected] => [downloadPath:protected] => /home/admin/web/sdmns.ru/public_html/downloads/ [timeout:protected] => [processOptions:protected] => Array ( ) [moveWithPhp:protected] => [debug:protected] => [allowedAudioFormats:protected] => Array ( [0] => best [1] => aac [2] => vorbis [3] => mp3 [4] => m4a [5] => opus [6] => wav ) )

как получить вывод из этого массива (например `[output]` или `[audio-format]`).

Спасибо.

Comment: Это у вас не массив, а объект класса YoutubeDl\YoutubeDl . Посмотрите документацию на библиотеку, которую используете.

Comment: Разобрался. Нашел обращения тут https://myrusakov.ru/sozdanie-klassa-php.html